# error : The element type "string" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</string>"

Tags: android, android-layout

ended the statement with  and clean the the project still i am getting the same error ,here i am placing the code

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">LiveWallpaper1</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="wallpaper_description">wallpaper descriptioning></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you please post what error you are getting?

Comment: Check if you have a typo at `wallpaper descriptioning>` and if that confuses the parser. Otherwise, provide more details!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is here

wallpaper descriptioning>

the '>' at the end is not allowed because it is a special character. try to replace it with \u003E, which is the unicode definition. for other unicode definitions refer here

http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0

hope this works

Answer (score 1):

On the last string line remove the '>' character before your

```
</string>
```

tag.  That is causing your error.